# How to make this plot more visible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code I used, the goal is to visualize the evolution of covid in north africa

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
covid <- read.csv("owid-covid-data.csv")
covid
as.Date(covid %>% select(date), "%d%b%Y")
covid %>%
  filter(location %in% c("Tunisia", "Morocco", "Libya")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y= new_cases,color = location, group = location)) +
  geom_line()
```

This is the dataset I used, as you can see the X_axis is day-to-day therefore it's a bit condensed
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipjCm.png)

And this is the plot, you can't see anything in the X_axis, I want to be able to discern the dates maybe use weeks or months to scale instead of days
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGDbx.png)

I read somewhere that the problem could be the date column being of type string but I didn't know how to use as.date() properly

Comment: Try with `filter(...) %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% ggplot(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `+ scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month")` to the end of your `ggplot` call (I just put 1 month as a guess, feel free to change accordingly).

If that doesn't work, it's probably because, as you suggested, the `date` column could be type "string" (when referring to a string's object class, R will call it a `character`, or `chr`). In that case, go ahead and change the `date` column by running `covid$date <- as.Date(covid$date)` before running your `ggplot` command.

As an additional note, if you're ever curious what type of variable you're dealing with, you can run the `class()` command, like `class(covid$date)`. Or, if you want to see the composition a whole dataset, you can use `str()`, like `str(covid)`.